# jQuery Drop Down has no method 'val'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

Below is a simple jQuery `if` statement I'm trying to use on my ASP MVC web page, but I continually get the error

```
Object #drpProducerType has no method 'val'
```

I also tried using the `:selected` syntax, but got the same results. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var value = ('#drpProducerType:selected').val();
    var value2 = ('#drpProducerType').val();
    alert(value);
    if (('#drpProducerType').val() == "S") {
        alert(('#drpProducerType').val());
        $('#DSSfields').removeClass('noSee');
        $('#DSSfields').addClass('seeMe');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `$`

```
if ($('#drpProducerType').val() == "S") {
     alert($('#drpProducerType').val());
     $('#DSSfields').removeClass('noSee');
     $('#DSSfields').addClass('seeMe');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the `$` on your jQuery selector. Change it to:

```
if ($('#drpProducerType').val() == "S") {
```